problem in SOAP requests using zeep in Docker container
Developed an APIRest with FastAPI and Python 11. I am using the library zeep to sign a request to consume a SOAP API and in my local environment it works correctly. When the application runs on a Docker container it fails on the line where the request is made. Simply stop the container, don’t show any error log.
Below is the code snippet
from fastapi import FastAPI
from requests import Session as RequestSession
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature
from zeep.transports import Transport

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    request = {
            'SolicitudDatosLocalizacion':{
                'TipoIdentificacion': '1',
                'Identificacion': 'xxxxxxxxx',
                'PrimerApellido': 'XXXXXXXX',
                'Usuario': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
                'Clave': 'xxxxx',
            }
        }
    session = RequestSession()
    session.cert = "service_public_key.pem"
    transport_certificate = Transport(session=session)
    signature_config = Signature(key_file="service_private_key.key", certfile="c55.crt")
    user_name_token = UsernameToken('x-xxxxxxx.x', 'xxx-xx--xx')
    client = Client(
        'https://demo-servicesesb.datacredito.com.co:443/wss/localizacion/services/ServicioLocalizacion?wsdl', 
        wsse = CustomSignature([user_name_token, signature_config]), 
        transport = transport_certificate
    )
    service = client.bind('ServicioLocalizacion', 'ServicioLocalizacionPort.dmz.https')
    response = service.consultarDatosLocalizacion(request)#Error
    print(response)
    return {"Hello": "World"}

Initially I thought it was an error associated with some dependency of xmlsec (used for wsse.Signature()) but not, it is when the request is made. Please your help !

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Just the Dockerfile on its own isn't really enough to understand what might be going wrong here.  (If the .env file is significant, it is not being read – ENV does not support command substitution and you're setting a variable named $(grep to a multi-work string value.)

Do some simple tests and it really isn’t xmlsec’s problem. For some strange reason it fails just at the time of making the request. I updated the question, thank you @DavidMaze
